# How to create a protocol extend existing protocol and change required to optional?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Is it possible to override existing protocol and make it optional? For example, in CUSTOMTableViewDataSource, compiler should not generate warnings if it does not implement `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`.

```
@protocol CUSTOMTableViewDataSource <UITableViewDataSource>
@optional
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end
```

Comment: You are not "overriding" an existing protocol. You are adopting it (in another protocol). CUSTOMTableViewDataSource _inherits_ from UITableViewDataSource in that sense. But this is not like class inheritance.

Comment: You should ask yourself _why_ you want to do this. It is a silly thing to want to do.

Comment: I'm trying to define a protocol extends UITableViewDataSource, if anyone adopt this protocol implemented any methods in the UITableViewDataSource, it will use that method, if not, it will use my own internal implementation. In this case, `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;` is not required.

Comment: A bit more explaination, I'm trying to create an object which implement all UITableViewDataSource's methods, but also give user an option to override any UITableViewDataSource's methods.

Comment: The user can just subclass your class.

Comment: Subclass is not my option, in many cases, the override data source object is a UIViewController instance. I think I will have to copy all methods over to this CUSTOMTableViewDataSource protocol. Looks silly, but seems like the only way to do it.  THANKS for the explaination. @matt

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the CUSTOMTableViewDataSource protocol that adopts the UITableViewDataSource protocol, but this means, by definition, that if a class adopts the CUSTOMTableViewDataSource protocol, it *also* adopts the UITableViewDataSource protocol — and therefore the compiler will still warn if the UITableViewDataSource required methods are not implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid the complier will generate warning here. A protocol has @required and @optional methods which are declared when they are created. In your case, if you open UITableView.h file you can clearly see both the methods

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

are declared as @required methods & the contents of UITableView.h are locked, hence you cannot modify it. So in your case, talking about this two methods the answer is no. On the other hand, if I am defining a protocol, I can choose to declare methods @required and @optional based on my need.

Comment: Why do he say he cannot do it? Did you try it? Of course he can do it. There is no error message. His code will compile just fine. But he cannot avoid the _warnings_.

Comment: @matt yes I tried that. And you are right, the code will compile but my point being, he cannot do that without compiler giving a warning & neither it is a good practice to adopt protocols this way. Hence I asked him to check for [at]required and [at]optional methods first. Thanks.